# Adding view to flexboxlayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-flexboxlayout

At the click of a button, I create one textview programmatically and add them to flexboxlayout. Why is only one view added?

```
mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        int i = 1;
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            flexboxLayout.setFlexDirection(FlexDirection.ROW_REVERSE);
            flexboxLayout.setFlexWrap(FlexWrap.WRAP);
            flexboxLayout.setJustifyContent(JustifyContent.CENTER);
            final TextViewR textViewR = new TextViewR(getApplicationContext(), "Text " + Integer.toString(i++)); //setting text here
            FlexboxLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FlexboxLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            lp.setOrder(1);
            textViewR.setLayoutParams(lp);
            flexboxLayout.addView(textViewR);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume `TextViewR` is your custom `TextView`.

You should change

```
`FlexboxLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FlexboxLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);`
```

to

```
`FlexboxLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FlexboxLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);`
```

since `textViewR.setLayoutParams(lp);` is setting the flexboxlayout parameters to the textview and your parameters are telling the textview to match parent which is the flexbox.

Comment: Anyway it hasn`t helped

Comment: Did you try removing `flexboxLayout.setJustifyContent(JustifyContent.CENTER);` and `lp.setOrder(1);` Just in case